# Dirty background on png product images in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, product-images, magento2.1.0, watermark

[image: Original] Original

[image: Result] Magento

I upgraded to Magento 2.1.0 from Magento 2.07 and now my png-formatted product images looks like above. I tried already disabled cache, changed image color profile and re-uploaded but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like php GD or ImageMagick problem, what php extensions you use for image compression and maybe you need to update latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I removed image watermark on admin panel and now it's working fine.